# Reset form inputs with Signal Preact

Tags: reactjs, preact

Is it possible to clear/reset the input fields after a form is submitted using signals? For instance, in the following simple form I have the following:

```
const formData = signal({ firstName: "", lastName: "" })

const Register = () => {

//function to make all keys pairs equal to an empty string
function initialState(input) {
        return Object.keys(input).forEach(i => input[i] = "");
};

function setFormData(name, value) {
        return formData.value = {...formData.value, [name]: value};
};

function handleInputChange (e) {
 const { name, value } = e.target;
 setFormData(name, value);
};
function registerUser (e){
 e.preventDefault();
 initialState(formData.value);
};

return(
  <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
   <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="First Name"
    name="firstName"
    value={formData.value.firstName}
    onChange="{handleInputChange}"
   />
   <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Last Name"
    name="lastName"
    value={formData.value.lastName}
    onChange="{handleInputChange}"
   />
<button>Submit</button>
  </form>
)
}
```

From the above, what I have noticed is that the inputs get clear once I type any word in any of the input fields after I click on the submit button.

Unlike useState, everything gets clear after submitting the form, I suspect is due to the fact that it re-renders all the components, which is not the case for Signals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using React or Preact (as you've left that out) and do you want the input fields to reset or not? "Unlike useState, everything gets clear after submitting the form" -- this sounds like you don't want it cleared?